# Evaluating Parentheses and Brackets as Integers

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, balanced-string, recursion

Write a program that takes in a string of the four characters `()[]` that satisfies these points:

- Every left parenthesis `(` has a matching right parenthesis `)`.
- Every left bracket `[` has a matching right bracket `]`.
- Matching pairs of parentheses and brackets won't overlap. e.g. `[(])` is invalid because the matching brackets are not fully contained in the matching parentheses, nor vice-versa.
- The first and last characters are a matching pair of parentheses or brackets. So `([]([]))` and `[[]([])]` are valid but `[]([])` is not.

(A [grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) for the input format is `<input> ::= [<input>*] | (<input>*)`.)

Each pair of matching parentheses and brackets evaluates to a non-negative integer:

- The values of pairs inside matching parentheses are all *summed*. The empty  match `()` has value [`0`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum).
- The values of pairs inside matching brackets are all *multiplied*. The empty match `[]` has value [`1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product).

<sup>(The [sum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28x%2C%20n%3D%200%20to%200%29) or [product](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product%28x%2C%20n%3D%200%20to%200%29) of one number is that same number.)</sup>

For example, `([](())([][])[()][([[][]][][])([][])])` can be broken down and evaluated as `9`:

```
([](())([][])[()][([[][]][][])([][])])    <input>
(1 (0 )(1 1 )[0 ][([1 1 ]1 1 )(1 1 )])    <handle empty matches>
(1 0   2     0   [(1     1 1 )2     ])    <next level of matches>
(1 0   2     0   [3           2     ])    <and the next>
(1 0   2     0   6                   )    <and the next>
9                                         <final value to output>
```

Another example:

```
[([][][][][])([][][])([][][])(((((([][]))))))]    <input>
[(1 1 1 1 1 )(1 1 1 )(1 1 1 )((((((1 1 ))))))]
[5           3       3       (((((2     )))))]
[5           3       3       ((((2       ))))]
[5           3       3       (((2         )))]
[5           3       3       ((2           ))]
[5           3       3       (2             )]
[5           3       3       2               ]
90                                                <output>
```

Your program needs to evaluate and print the integer represented by the entire input string. You can assume the input is valid. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Instead of a program, you may write a function that takes in a string and prints or returns the integer.

Comment: Asking on behalf of the Python submission for clarification: Program only, or are functions/return value okay?

Comment: Might be good to edit the question then. In a previous question, I was told that functions are not valid if it says "write a program" in the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## CJam, 23

```
q"])(""1]:*0]:+["4/ers~
```

With BIG credits to Dennis! [Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%22%5D)(%22%221%5D%3A*0%5D%3A%2B%5B%224%2Fers~&input=%5B(%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D)(%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D)(%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D)((((((%5B%5D%5B%5D))))))%5D)

**Explanation:**

The program converts the input to a CJam expression then evaluates it.
`[…]` becomes `[…1]:*` (append 1 and multiply)
`(…)` becomes `[…0]:+` (append 0 and add)

```
q              read input
"])("          characters we want to replace
"1]:*0]:+["    replacement strings, concatenated
4/             split into strings of length 4: ["1]:*" "0]:+" "["]
er             replace (transliterate) the 3 characters with the 3 strings
s              convert the result (mixed characters and strings) to string
~              evaluate
```

Comment: Transliteration saves 4 bytes: `q"])(""1]:*0]:+["4/ers~`

Comment: @Dennis whaaa! That's insane, you can do that??

Comment: *You* are asking *me*? :P

Comment: @Dennis How would the creator of CJam know about such feature's existence??

Answer (score 8):

## Common Lisp - 98

```lisp
(lambda(s)(eval(read-from-string(#1=ppcre:regex-replace-all"\\["(#1#"]"(#1#"\\("s"(+")")")"(*"))))
```

1. Replace `(` by `(+`
2. Replace `[` by `(*`
3. Replace `]` by `)`
4. Read from string
5. Eval

This requires `cl-ppcre` library to be loaded in current lisp image.

#### Explanation

Functions `*` and `+` are variadic and return their neutral value when given no arguments.
For your examples, the evaluated lisp form are the following ones:

```
(+ (*) (+ (+)) (+ (*) (*)) (* (+)) (* (+ (* (*) (*)) (*) (*)) (+ (*) (*))))
=> 9
```

and

```
(* (+ (*) (*) (*) (*) (*)) (+ (*) (*) (*)) (+ (*) (*) (*))
   (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (*) (*))))))))
=> 90
```

#### Without regexes - 183 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(do(r(x(coerce s'list))c)((not x)(eval(read-from-string(coerce(reverse r)'string))))(setq c(pop x))(push(case c(#\[ (push #\* r)#\()(#\] #\))(#\( (push #\+ r) #\()(t c))r)))
```

#### C'mon, Lisp - 16 bytes (experimental)

```
+((<r*([<r)]<rRE
```

Other languages are so terse that I am tempted to make my own golfing language based on Common Lisp, for shorter string manipulations. Currently there is no spec, and the eval function is the following one:

```lisp
(defun cmon-lisp (expr &rest args)
  (apply
   (lambda (s)
     (let (p q)
       (loop for c across expr
             do (case c
                  (#\< (push (pop p) q))
                  (#\r
                   (let ((a1 (coerce q 'string)) (a2 (coerce p 'string)))
                     (setf p nil
                           q nil
                           s
                             (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all
                              (cl-ppcre:quote-meta-chars a1) s a2))))
                  (#\R
                   (setf s
                           (if (string= s "")
                               nil
                               (read-from-string s))))
                  (#\E (setf s (eval s)))
                  (t (push c p))))
       s))
   args))
```

Tests:

```
(cmon-lisp "+((<r*([<r)]<rRE" "([] [] ([] []))")
=> 4
```

- there is an implicit argument called `s` and two stacks, `p` and `q`.
- characters in source code are pushed to `p`.
- `<` : pops from `p` and pushes to `q`.
- `r` : replaces in `s` (must be a string) from characters in `q` to charactes in `p`; result is stored in `s`; `p` and `q` are emptied.
- `R` : read from string `s`, store result in variable `s`.
- `E` : eval form `s`, store result in `s`.

Comment: Funyy how lisp is used to do something with brackets here.

Comment: @SydKerckhove You comment just make me think of an appropriate Clojure answer. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
L?*F+1yMbqb+YbsyMbyvsXzJ"])"+R\,J
```

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3F*F%2B1yMbqb%2BYbsyMbyvsXzJ%22%5D)%22%2BR%5C%2CJ&input=%5B(%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D)(%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D)(%5B%5D%5B%5D%5B%5D)((((((%5B%5D%5B%5D))))))%5D&debug=0)

*1 byte thanks to @Jakube.*

We start by parsing the input. The input format is close to Python, but not quite. We need commas after each parenthesized or bracketed group. The comma at the end of a bracketed group is unnecessary, but harmless. To accomplish this, we use this code:

```
vsXzJ"])"+R\,J
  X               Translate
   z              in the input
     "])"         the characters "])"
    J             which we will save to J to
             J    J
         +R\,     with each character mapped to itself plus a ",".
 s                Combine the list to a string.
v                  Evaluate as a Python literal.
```

This will leave an extra `,` at the end of the string, which will wrap the whole object in a tuple, but this is harmless, because the tuple will be summed, and so have a value equal to its element.

Now that the string is parsed, we must find its value. This is done using a user defined function, `y`, which is called on the parsed object. the function is defined as follows:

```
L?*F+1yMbqb+YbsyMb
L                     Define a function, y(b), which returns the following:
 ?       qb+Yb        We form a ternary whose condition is whether the input, b,
                      equals the inputplus the empty list, Y. This is true if
                      and only if b is a list.
      yMb             If so, we start by mapping y over every element of b.
  *F+1                We then take the product of these values. The +1 ensures
                      that the empty list will return 1.
                yMb   Otherwise, we start by mapping y over every element of b.
               s      Then, we sum the results.
```

Comment: @Jakube Right, the unary summation has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

## Emacs lisp, 94

The format looks very lispy, so I thought a simple transformation might work:

```
(defun e()(format-replace-strings'(("("."(+")("["."(*")("]".")")))(eval(read(buffer-string))))
```

The intermediate format looks something like (for the example in the question):

```
(+(*)(+(+))(+(*)(*))(*(+))(*(+(*(*)(*))(*)(*))(+(*)(*))))
```

We're helped by the fact that addition and multiplication already do what we want with an empty argument list.

Degolfed, and interactive, for you playing pleasure:

```
(defun paren_eval()
  (interactive "*")
  (format-replace-strings '(("(" . "(+")
                            ("[" . "(*")
                            ("]" . ")")))
  (eval (read (buffer-string)))
)
```

Comment: I should have read more closely - the Common Lisp solution takes exactly the same approach!

Comment: We need more Emacs Lisp answers!. Btw, I did not count but you could golf it a little more by using a lambda, taking a string as a parameter and removing `interactive`  (instead of buffer-string, use read-from-string).

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 111 bytes

```
[\([](1+x)[]\)]
$1
\[]
1x
\(\)
x
(\[a*)1(?=1*x1*x)
$1a
a(?=a*x(1*)x)
$1
(\[1*x)1*x
$1
)`(\(1*)x(?=1*x)
$1
[^1]
<empty line>
```

Gives output in unary.

Each line should go to its own file but you can run the code as one file with the `-s` flag. E.g.:

```
> retina -s brackets <input_1
111111111
```

Explanation comes later.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 349 characters

A simple recursive approach. Expects the string to be the first argument used to call the program.

```java
import java.util.*;class K{int a=0,b;String c;public static void main(String[]a){K b=new K();b.c=a[0];System.out.print(b.a());}int a(){switch(c.charAt(a++)){case'(':b=0;for(int a:b())b+=a;break;case'[':b=1;for(int a:b())b*=a;}a++;return b;}List<Integer>b(){List d=new ArrayList();char c;while((c=this.c.charAt(a))!=']'&&c!=')')d.add(a());return d;}}
```

Expanded:

```java
import java.util.*;

class K {
    int a =0, b;
    String c;
    public static void main(String[] a){
        K b = new K();
        b.c = a[0];
        System.out.print(b.a());
    }
    int a(){
        switch (c.charAt(a++)){
            case '(':
                b =0;
                for (int a : b())
                    b += a;
                break;
            case '[':
                b =1;
                for (int a : b())
                    b *= a;
        }
        a++;
        return b;
    }
    List<Integer> b(){
        List d = new ArrayList();
        char c;
        while ((c= this.c.charAt(a)) != ']' && c != ')')
            d.add(a());
        return d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, 108

Done as an interpreter rather than rewrite-and-eval. Not a great showing, but fun to write anyway.

```
push@s,/[[(]/?[(ord$_&1)x2]:do{($x,$y,$z,$t)=(@{pop@s},@{pop@s});
[$t?$x*$z:$x+$z,$t]}for<>=~/./g;say$s[0][0]
```

Un-golfed:

```
# For each character in the first line of stdin
for (<> =~ /./g) {
    if ($_ eq '[' or $_ eq '(') {
        # If it's an opening...
        # ord('[') = 91 is odd, ord('(') = 40 is even
        push @stack, [ ( ord($_) & 1) x 2 ];
        # so we will push [1, 1] on the stack for brackets and [0, 0] for parens.
        # one of these is used as the flag for which operator the context is, and
        # the other is used as the initial (identity) value.
    } else {
        # otherwise, assume it's a closing
        ($top_value, $top_oper) = @{ pop @stack };
        ($next_value, $next_oper) = @{ pop @stack };
        # merge the top value with the next-to-top value according to the
        # next-to-top operator. The top operator is no longer used.
        $new_value = $next_oper
            ? $top_value * $next_value
            : $top_value + $next_value
        push @stack, [ $new_value, $next_oper ];
    }
}

say $stack[0][0]; # print the value remaining on the stack.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 99

I tried a variety of methods but the shortest I could get was basically just a replacement and eval. I was pleasantly surprised to find that I could leave all the trailing `,`s, as Python can parse `[1,2,]` and the final trailing comma just puts the whole thing in a tuple. The only other non-straightforward part would be the `ord(c)%31%7` to seperate out the different characters (it evaluates to `2`,`3`,`1`,`0` for `(`,`)`,`[`,`]` respectively)

```py
F=lambda s:eval(''.join(["],1),","reduce(int.__mul__,[","sum([","]),"][ord(c)%31%7]for c in s))[0]
```

Comment: This does not work as a program, does it? The question asks for a program, so I don't think providing a function meets the requirements. At least that's what people told me last time I submitted a function when it said "program" in the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure - 66 bytes

Notice that `([] (()) ([] []) [()] [([[] []] [] []) ([] [])])` is a valid Clojure form. So:

```
#(letfn[(g[x](apply(if(list? x)+ *)(map g x)))](g(read-string %)))
```

- This is an anonymous function taking a string, reading it and giving to `g`.
- The local `g` function apply `+` or `*` to the result of the invocation of `g` on sub-elements of its arguments.
- The base case of the recursion is a little subtle: it is reached when `x` in an empty sequence; `(map g x)` returns `nil`, and `apply` returns the neutral value for the operation.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 301

a bit of a different approach than TheNumberOne's answer, although mine is also recursive in nature. Input is taken from the command line. The void method saves a few bytes when removing the characters that are no longer needed.

```
enum E{I;String n;public static void main(String[]r){I.n=r[0];System.out.print(I.e());}int e(){int v=0;if(n.charAt(0)=='('){for(s("(");n.charAt(0)!=')';)v+=e();s(")");}else if(n.charAt(0)=='['){v=1;for(s("[");n.charAt(0)!=']';)v*=e();s("]");}return v;}void s(String c){n=n.substring(1+n.indexOf(c));}}
```

expanded:

```
enum EvaluatingParenthesesAndBrackets{
    AsIntegers;
    String input;
    public static void main(String[]args){
        AsIntegers.input=args[0];
        System.out.print(AsIntegers.evaluate());
    }
    int evaluate(){
        int value=0;
        if(input.charAt(0)=='('){
            for(substringAfterChar("(");input.charAt(0)!=')';)
                value+=evaluate();
            substringAfterChar(")");
        }
        else if(input.charAt(0)=='['){
            value=1;
            for(substringAfterChar("[");input.charAt(0)!=']';)
                value*=evaluate();
            substringAfterChar("]");
        }
        return value;
    }
    void substringAfterChar(String character){
        input=input.substring(1+input.indexOf(character));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>117</s> <s>110</s> 109 bytes

```
def C(s,p=[0]):
 m=r=s[p[0]]=='[';p[0]+=1
 while s[p[0]]in'[(':t=C(s,p);r=r*t*m+(r+t)*(1-m)
 p[0]+=1;return r
```

One aspect I was struggling with is that the function basically has two return values: the product/sum, and the new position in the string. But I need a function that returns only the result, so returning a tuple does not work. This version uses a "reference" argument (list with one element), to pass the position back from the function.

I have a shorter version (103 bytes) that uses a global variable for the position. But that will only work on the first call. And a function that only works once seems a bit fishy. Not sure if it would be acceptable for code golf.

The algorithm is straightforward recursion. I tried a number of variations for the expression that updates the product/sum. I came up with a few versions that were exactly the same length, but none of them shorter.

I sort of expected that the approach that turns this into an expression that gets evaluated would probably win. But as they say: "To iterate is human, to recurse divine."

Comment: Functions now explicitly allowed :)

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Got a rules question that I was generally wondering about, but that might come into play here: If a solution is implemented as a function, does this imply that the function can be called more than once in a single run? For example, if it used a global variable that is only initialized correctly on the first call, would that be... wrong?

Comment: @Retro I'd say yes, it is wrong. The function should work any number of times without reinterpreting it.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 116 bytes

```
s=>+[...s].reduce((t,c)=>((x=c==']')||c==')'?t[1].push(t.shift().reduce((a,b)=>x?a*b:a+b,+x)):t.unshift([]),t),[[]])
```